# Get all combinations of summing numbers

Tags: excel, vba

Column A in sheet1 has the values [1,2,3,4,5,6] in range("A1:A6") and what I am trying to do is to get all the combinations of summing each two numbers and each three numbers and each four numbers and each five numbers
This is what I did till now but the results are not as I expected

```
Sub Test()
    Dim a, b, lr As Long, i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, ii As Long
    lr = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 1 To lr
        For j = i To lr
            For ii = j To lr
                Cells(i, ii + 1) = i & "+" & j & "+" & ii & "=" & i + j + ii
            Next ii
        Next j
    Next i
    With Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        a = .Offset(, 1).Resize(, .Columns.Count - 1).Value
        ReDim b(1 To UBound(a, 1) * UBound(a, 2), 1 To 1)
        For i = LBound(a) To UBound(a)
            For j = LBound(a, 2) To UBound(a, 2)
                If a(i, j) <> "" Then
                    k = k + 1
                    b(k, 1) = a(i, j)
                End If
            Next j
        Next i
        .Cells(1, .Columns.Count + 2).Resize(k).Value = b
    End With
End Sub
```

Example of the desired output:
Each two numbers together >>

```
Sub Test()
    Dim a, b, lr As Long, i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, ii As Long
    lr = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 1 To lr
        For j = i To lr
            Cells(i, j + 1) = i & "+" & j & "=" & i + j
        Next j
    Next i
    With Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        a = .Offset(, 1).Resize(, .Columns.Count - 1).Value
        ReDim b(1 To UBound(a, 1) * UBound(a, 2), 1 To 1)
        For i = LBound(a) To UBound(a)
            For j = LBound(a, 2) To UBound(a, 2)
                If a(i, j) <> "" Then
                    k = k + 1
                    b(k, 1) = a(i, j)
                End If
            Next j
        Next i
        .Cells(1, .Columns.Count + 2).Resize(k).Value = b
    End With
End Sub
```

### The results would be like that in column J

```
1+1=2
1+2=3
1+3=4
1+4=5
1+5=6
1+6=7
2+2=4
2+3=5
2+4=6
2+5=7
2+6=8
3+3=6
3+4=7
3+5=8
3+6=9
4+4=8
4+5=9
4+6=10
5+5=10
5+6=11
6+6=12
```

This is OK for each two numbers .. How can I get the results for each three numbers and for each four numbers and for each five numbers?

** @Vityata

```
Public Sub PrintArrayOnSingleLine(myArray As Variant)

    Dim i As Long, x As Long
    Dim textArray As String, temp As String
    
    For i = LBound(myArray) To UBound(myArray)
        textArray = textArray & myArray(i)
        x = x + Val(myArray(i))
        temp = temp & "+" & myArray(i)
    Next i
    
    Dim myLastRow As Long
    myLastRow = LastRow(Worksheets(1).Name) + 1
    ActiveSheet.Cells(myLastRow, 1) = Mid(temp, 2) & "=" & x
    
End Sub
```

I have edited the procedure as you told me, but just one note, I can't get the same number to be summed. Example: `1+1=2`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- **Combination** (not repeating same values):

Copy the code below and run it. Then change the variable in `size = n`. The given numbers are in the `initialArray`. In the end, instead of printing the array as a `textArray`, add a variable to sum it:

```
Sub Main()
    
    Dim size As Long: size = 2
    Dim initialArray As Variant: initialArray = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
    Dim arr As Variant: ReDim arr(size - 1)
    Dim n As Long: n = UBound(arr) + 1
    
    EmbeddedLoops 0, size, initialArray, n, arr
    
End Sub

Function EmbeddedLoops(index As Long, size As Long, initialArray As Variant, n As Long, arr As Variant)
    
    Dim p As Variant
    
    If index >= size Then
        If Not AnyValueBiggerThanNext(arr) And Not AnyValueIsRepeated(arr) Then
            PrintArrayOnSingleLine arr
        End If
    Else
        For Each p In initialArray
            arr(index) = p
            EmbeddedLoops index + 1, size, initialArray, n, arr
        Next p
    End If
    
End Function

Public Function AnyValueBiggerThanNext(arr As Variant) As Boolean

    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr) - 1
        If arr(i) > arr(i + 1) Then
            AnyValueBiggerThanNext = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next i
    
    AnyValueBiggerThanNext = False

End Function

Public Function AnyValueIsRepeated(arr As Variant) As Boolean
            
    On Error GoTo AnyValueIsRepeated_Error:
    
    Dim element As Variant
    Dim testCollection As New Collection
    
    For Each element In arr
        testCollection.Add "item", CStr(element)
    Next element
    
    AnyValueIsRepeated = False
    
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Function
    
AnyValueIsRepeated_Error:
    AnyValueIsRepeated = True
    
End Function

Public Sub PrintArrayOnSingleLine(myArray As Variant)

    Dim i As Long
    Dim textArray As String
    
    For i = LBound(myArray) To UBound(myArray)
        textArray = textArray & myArray(i)
    Next i
    
    Debug.Print textArray
    
End Sub
```

---

- **Permutation (repeating same values)**

---

```
Sub Main()
    
    Static size         As Long
    Static c            As Variant
    Static arr          As Variant
    Static n            As Long
    
    size = 3
    c = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
    
    n = UBound(c) + 1
    ReDim arr(size - 1)
    
    EmbeddedLoops 0, size, c, n, arr
    
End Sub

Function EmbeddedLoops(index, k, c, n, arr)
    
    Dim i                   As Variant
    
    If index >= k Then
        PrintArrayOnSingleLine arr
    Else
        For Each i In c
            arr(index) = i
            EmbeddedLoops index + 1, k, c, n, arr
        Next i
    End If

End Function

Public Sub PrintArrayOnSingleLine(myArray As Variant)

    Dim counter     As Integer
    Dim textArray     As String
    
    For counter = LBound(myArray) To UBound(myArray)
        textArray = textArray & myArray(counter)
    Next counter
    
    Debug.Print textArray
    
End Sub
```

Sources (Disclaimer - [from my blog](https://www.vitoshacademy.com)):

- [VBA Nested Loop with Recursion](https://www.vitoshacademy.com/vba-nested-loops-with-recursion/)
- [VBA All Combinations](https://www.vitoshacademy.com/vba-all-combinations/)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your support. How can I edit the code so as to put the results in the sheet?

Comment: The results are in the immediate window (CTRL+G), displayed from `textArray`. Try looping through the elements of the array and write them into a new cell every time.

Comment: I tried this `    For i = LBound(myArray) To UBound(myArray)
        textArray = textArray & myArray(i)
        Range("A" & i + 1).Value = textArray
    Next i
` but seems not to work

Comment: You had to have this on your digital "shelve" somewhere =)

Comment: @YasserKhalil - this one should print the `textArray` in the activesheet - https://gist.github.com/Vitosh/cfa045e48027b0a509f42b025dcef046

Comment: @JvdV - staying next to the elf :)

Comment: @Vityata Amazing. Just one more point, I just got the summation of each two numbers, how can I get the same result as I did in my code. example, `5+6=11` so as to get the resport correctly.

Comment: This is new for me that Vitoshacademy is your blog. I am very big fan of what you are posting on your blog. My pleasure.

Comment: In this function, the array is passed - `Public Sub PrintArrayOnSingleLine(myArray As Variant)`. So, in `myArray` the values would looks like this - `Array(5,6)`. In the function, loop through the array values and display them. Then sum them. Take a look at the other articles, the code above gives combinations, thus `1+1=2` will not be present.

Comment: Nice... Voted it up. But it returns a normal combination of N by k. In his example OP looks wanting also 1+1, 2+2, 3+3 etc. Understood that the code comes from your nice collection... Not extremely complicated to adapt the code, anyhow. And the algorithm for the ordinary maximum combinations **must look like this**!

Comment: @FaneDuru - thanks. I noted the `1+1=2` missing, that is why I commented it 2 comments above yours. Still, added the code, providing it.

Comment: I could see it now, but this does not change too much of what I wanted transmitting... I also think that instead of returning each combination in consecutive steps, it should be more interesting to put them in another array, which can be easily used, even to drop its content in a range, at once... Like he looks to need. And in the main `Sub` the 1D array can be extracted like a slice, from a range similar to the one OP tried showing in his question (no iteration). Maybe the `Sub` to have two arguments, one Optional and solution being chosen according to them... But, anyhow, nice piece of code!

Comment: I placed it in my collection, too... :)